# Confuse about ES5′s array extra methods' context

Tags: arrays, function, ecmascript-5

I try to use some ES5′s array extra methods like `map`, `some`, `forEach`

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(function (el) {
    console.log(this) // window
})
```

but I found the context in these methods is not the array which invoke them

but the  `Global context` like `window`.

In MDN's [opinion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

> When a function is called as a method of an object, its this is set to
>   the object the method is called on.

So what's exactly relationship between the array and the called method?

Comment: The anonymous callback function isn't a method of `Array`, `forEach()` is.

Answer (score 1):

If you look [on the developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) you'll see that the signature of `forEach` is:

> array.forEach(callback[, thisArg])

and then

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to forEach, it will be used as the this value for each callback invocation as if callback.call(thisArg, element, index, array) was called. If thisArg is undefined or null, the this value within the function depends on whether the function is in strict mode or not (passed value if in strict mode, global object if in non-strict mode).

So you won't ever receive the `array` as `this` unless you put it as the second argument of the `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is set to the array on which forEach is called **inside the `forEach` method**. However, the anonymous function you pass to the forEach method does not have its `this` set to the array since that function isn't called as a method on the array. (But you could supply the array to the `forEach` method as the [thisArg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), so `this` in the anonymous function would point to the array.

Example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.forEach(function (el) {
    console.log(this) // the Array
}, a);
```

or bind the function:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.forEach((function (el) {
    console.log(this) // the Array
}).bind(a));
```